# Get Count in Many to Many Relationship for record Editing

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables in my DB. `Classes`,`Registrations` and pivot table `class_registration`.

An event has classes and the user can select multiple classes for their registration. So if User A selects Class 1 twice and Class 2 once I save 1 row for each round, i.e 2 rows for Class 1 and 1 row for Class 2.

`Classes` table has the following fields

```
id | event_id | name | fees
```

`Registration` table has the following fields

```
id | event_id | user_id | fees | isPaid
```

`Class_Registration` pivot table has following fields

```
id | registration_id | class_id | unitFees
```

Following is the relationship in `registration` model

```
public function classes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Classes::class,'class_registrations','registration_id','class_id');
}
```

Following is my code for the controller

```
public function updateRegistration(UpdateRegistrationRequest $request, Registration $registration)
{
    return view('frontend.event.editRegistration',['event' => $registration->eventDetail,'registration' => $registration]);
}
```

I want to get the count of class in each `registration` so I can populate the data while editing `registration`.

Following is the view code

```
@foreach ($registration->classes as $class)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $class->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $class->maxEntry }}</td>
        <td>{{ $class->fees }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ html()->hidden('classes[]',$class->id) }}
            <select name="rounds_{{ $class->id }}" id="rounds" class="form-control" required="required">
                @for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
                    <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
                @endfor
             </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

How do I group them by `class_id` and display the count in the dropdown?

Comment: I am not understand the question completely. But I think you may try [WithCount](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models).

Comment: @ab_ab WithCount gives me total classes in one registration. I want to know in one registration count of classes group by class_id.

Comment: You could do something like this.
`->withCount(['table_field as my_field' => function($q) {
            $q->where('another_table_field', '>', 'condition value');
        }])`. Not tested but you can test it with group by or something. or you may apply inside the loop.